# What exactly does the 'protect' method in VpnService.java

Tags: java, android, sockets, vpn

I was going through VpnService.java from the ToyVpn project.

I see these following lines in the run method initially

```
 // Create a DatagramChannel as the VPN tunnel.
 tunnel = DatagramChannel.open();

 // Protect the tunnel before connecting to avoid loopback.
 if (!protect(tunnel.socket())) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot protect the tunnel");
 }
```

I understand that the first line creates a Datagram/UDP channel to connect to a remote server. But I do not understand what exactly the "protect" method is doing.

Could someone explain to me in as much technical detail. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a function from the [android.net.VpnService library](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService.html) that is imported in the ToyVpnService.java class as you can see in [the source code](https://code.google.com/p/android-source-browsing/source/browse/samples/ToyVpn/src/com/example/android/toyvpn/ToyVpnService.java?repo=platform--development&name=android-sdk-adt_r16.0.1&r=9ad3f40880fa998063e6d3bcb994e918b44272bc)

You can find what it does [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService.html#protect(int))

> **public boolean protect (int socket)**
>
> Added in API level 14
>
> Protect a socket from VPN connections. After
>   protecting, data sent through this socket will go directly to the
>   underlying network, so its traffic will not be forwarded through the
>   VPN. This method is useful if some connections need to be kept outside
>   of VPN. For example, a VPN tunnel should protect itself if its
>   destination is covered by VPN routes. Otherwise its outgoing packets
>   will be sent back to the VPN interface and cause an infinite loop.
>   This method will fail if the application is not prepared or is
>   revoked.
>
> The socket is NOT closed by this method.
>
> Returns true on success.

Comment: Ahh! So if I have forwarded all traffic to pass through the tunnel, then this socket will be protected from that kind of forwarding.

Am I right?

Comment: @AbhishekVasisht as it says: *After protecting, data sent through this socket will go directly to the underlying network, so its traffic will not be forwarded through the VPN.*